# How to properly structure "for scores less than 10 or greater than 90" within an if statement?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm simply trying the following:

```
if score < 10 or > 90:
    print(f"Your score is {score}, you go together x and y.")
```

but it gives an error:

```
    if score < 10 or > 90:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Would someone explain the *reason* behind it not liking > 90? Its type is integer. Instead of just looking at the solution I want to understand why.

Comment: `... or score > 90:` - `> 90` is not a syntactically valid expression in and of itself, `<` is a binary operator that requires two operands (from https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons, the first `or_expr` is required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>`  and `or` are *binary* operators. You mustn't confuse coding with natural language, think more in the ways of statement or predicate logic. The correct syntax here would be:

```
if score < 10 or score > 90:
    # ...
```

You can, however, use comparison operator chaining to get the same condition (possibly more readable):

```
if not (10 <= score <= 90):
    # ...
```